# Is there a polyfill for std::once_flag?

Tags: c++, std

In a C++ program, I'm using a library which uses `std::once_flag`, but it seems like the compiler (`arm-none-eabi-g++`) doesn't support that. Is there a polyfill for this `std::once_flag`?

I saw this on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117468/stdonce-flag-and-stdcall-once-implementation but I was wondering whether there is an official polyfill.

It doesn't matter whether the polyfill supports multithreading or not, as my target device doesn't support it anyways.

Comment: If your device doesn't support multithreading, why are you trying to use C++11 multithreading features?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It's used in a library I'm using

Comment: ... for multithreading, presumably. Which you cannot do. So it seems you are using the wrong library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an "official" polyfill. The standard is the official definition of the language and it is up to compilers to implement that. If you cannot use GCC 4.8 (the first GCC to implement "complete" C++11) then you will have to live with reproducing its behaviour as best you can, with code written by yourself or others.

*(It's possible that your problem stems not from the GCC version, but from the specific port/package/platform; however, since you did not tell us the name/version of your toolchain, or your build command, or the actual problem that you encounter, I will simply assume that this is not the case here.)*

So, the code you found is what you've got. However, you should bear in mind that your program will have undefined behaviour. Ideally you will upgrade your compiler or switch back to C++03-compatible coding. Personally I'd recommend falling back on *Boost.Thread* until you're using C++11 in totality.

Or, y'know, simply *don't use `std::once_flag`*, a helper structure for `std::call_once`, which is all about multithreading… which you claim that your device doesn't support.